# Is there any client-side control is ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As far as I understand,

- all ASP.NET controls are [Server-side](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25167/aspnet-server-control), meaning that they require a round-trip to the server in order to be updated.
- HTML controls can be [both Client-side, and server-side](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/difference-between-server-side-control-and-client-side-control).

Is there any client-side control is ASP.NET?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_client_side.htm

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio